# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not working using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to set-up a system where 3rd party sites can interact with my Codeigniter site but I need a way of grabbing their domain. Here is a test I conducted to try and get it working.

I have this on a 3rd party site

```
    echo file_get_contents('http://mycodeigniterdomian.com/');
```

and on a fresh CI install (2.1.0) I have this in the welcome controller

```
public function index()
{
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');

    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    echo 'Hello World';

    echo '<br><br> ------------------------------------------- <br><br>';

    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    echo '<br><br> ------------------------------------------- <br><br>';

    print_r($_SERVER);

    echo '<br><br> ------------------------------------------- <br><br>';

    print_r($this->input->server());

    echo '<br><br> ------------------------------------------- <br><br>';

    echo $this->agent->referrer();

}
```

But neither $_SERVER or agent->referrer() return anything.

I have also tried the code outside Codeigniter but on the same domain and HTTP_REFERER is working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The visitor of the page (page that call HTTP_REFERER) needs to be redirected from some other page (click from web page)

for example if you click on http://mycodeigniterdomian.com/, it will send

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823291/serverhttp-referer-not-working-using-codeigniter
```

to http://mycodeigniterdomian.com/

if it does not come from any page, no value is sent for HTTP_REFERER

Comment: Hi sorry I don't think I have explained it well. The first code snippet would be on a different page (eg mydomain.com/index.php) so if a user goes to that page then it should run the script and display the referer as mydomain.com/index.php. I can get this to work outside codeigniter no problem its just not working with it.

Comment: I've been using HTTP_REFERER in CodeIgniter for logging without any problem. This might be unrelated but have you check your .htaccess?